# TypeScript union type between "newable" or function

Tags: typescript

I have a function, `foo`, which I want to accept a parameter `bar` which is either a "newable" (`{ new(...args: Array<any>): any; }`) or a function returning type any.

I have tried the following two methods, but in the first example `bar` has a type of `() => any` according to the compiler, and in the second example I get a syntax parsing error on the `)` of `() => any` with the message "Type expected".

```
type Newable = { new (...args: Array<any>): any; };

function foo1(bar: () => any | Newable) {

}

function foo2(bar: Newable | () => any) {

}
```

Please note I do not want to use the `Function` type - I want to have finer control over the function specifics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose the `() => any` in parentheses. Like this:

```
type Newable = { new (...args: Array<any>): any; };

function foo1(bar: (() => any) | Newable) {
    //...
}

function foo2(bar: Newable | (() => any)) {
    //...
}
```